# How can I transfer files from Window 8 to Windows 7 (since Easy Transfer won't work)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, file-transfer, windows-easy-transfer

I am trying to transfer files from my Acer Windows 8 computer to my new Gateway laptop with Windows 7.  I have finally learned that Easy Transfer program will not work in this direction.  Please advise the best solution for transfer of my files to Windows 7.

Comment: Use USB disk / ext HDD? Or if both computers are on the same network, just create a shared folder, and you can download it from the shared folder.

Comment: Or use Cloud Storage like Dropbox or anything else.